How to prevent stack attributes on tRPC response?
I'm building a POC using T3 Framework which uses tRPC and can't find a way to prevent the stack propriety on the HTTP response.
I tried to set NODE_ENV to "production" and still get the stack trace sposed to the frontend.
PS: when the template is found, I don't need extra error handling, my problem is exactly when template repository doesn't return a valid template.
PS2: I made some simplifications just to get to the point, this code reproduces the problem I facing.
My code:
export const templatesRouter = createTRPCRouter({
  get: publicProcedure
    .input(z.object({id: z.string().min(3)}))
    .query(async ({input}) => {
      const template = await TemplateRepository.get(input.id);
      if(!template) throw new TRPCError({
        code: 'NOT_FOUND',
        message: 'Template not found',
      })
      return template
    }),
});


The response I get:
{
  "error": {
    "json": {
      "message": "Template not found",
      "code": -32004,
      "data": {
        "code": "NOT_FOUND",
        "httpStatus": 404,
        "stack": "TRPCError: Template not found\n    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/server/api/routers/templates.ts:46:30)...",
        "path": "templates.get",
        "zodError": null
      }
    }
  }
}

I expect:
{
  "error": {
    "json": {
      "message": "Template not found",
      "code": -32004,
      "data": {
        "code": "NOT_FOUND",
        "httpStatus": 404,
        "path": "templates.get",
        "zodError": null
      }
    }
  }
}


Can't you just override the stack on the error object?
const x = new TRPCError({ code: "CONFLICT" });
if(isProd) x.stack = "";


or use a centralized errorFormatter:
https://trpc.io/docs/server/error-formatting
export const trpc = initTRPC.context<Context>().create({
  errorFormatter({ shape }) {
    return {
      ...shape,
      data: {
        ...shape.data,
        stack: isProd ? '' : shape.data.stack
      },
    };
  },
});

If you use the Next-TRPC adapter there seems to be an additional way of doing this. I did not use or test this way.
https://trpc.io/docs/server/error-handling#handling-errors
